Launching Apache Airflow with Pyenv how does it work
I am reading this blog on how to launch Airflow locally. It is pretty straight forward if you want to do it from the command line. Except that I want to launch it from PyCharm. I am not sure how to translate the shell script that launches Airflow from the command line to one that will launch it form PyCharm. This is the inside of the script (I am using Pyenv).
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$PYENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"

export PYENV_ROOT="/Users/Josefa/.pyenv"
exec "/usr/local/opt/pyenv/bin/pyenv" exec "$program" "$@"

which from the blog you just use this command that points to the above bash launcher script.
NO_PROXY="*" AIRFLOW_HOME="$(pwd)/airflow" airflow standalone
In this case I figured
program=airflow and $@=standalone.
I imagine that this will call at the end some sort of Python script but I can figure out how.
Does anybody has any idea?
